# Merging files from most recent

Tags: bash, cat

I wish to get the command for merging files from the most recent to the oldest in bash from a particular directory. Meaning files with newer dates are saved before ones with older dates

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: You mean you want to order the files by date, and `cat` them in this order? Have a look at `man ls` for "sort by date" options. This will only work if the file names don't contain funny characters.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity No, I just know that for merging from oldest to recent
`for file in `ls -tr .*`; do  cat $file >> Save.txt; done`
So I was wandering if there is any for saving starting from recent dates

Comment: Regarding your many questions with no accepted answer, please see https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

In the `zsh` shell, the globbing pattern and globing qualifier `*(.om)` would expand to all names of regular files in the current directory, ordered by their modification timestamp. The most recently modified file is first in the resulting list. If the directory does not have any regular files, the pattern generates an error in the shell.

In the `zsh` shell, therefore,

```bsh
cat ./*(.om) >Save.txt
```

or, for many thousands of files, with a loop,

```bsh
for name ( ./*(.om) ) cat $name >Save.txt
```

Calling this from `bash`:

```bsh
zsh -c 'for name ( ./*(.om) ) cat $name >Save.txt'
```

You may also use `zargs` in `zsh`, which is a sort of built-in variant of `xargs`:

```bsh
autoload -U zargs
zargs -- ./*(.om) -- cat -- >Save.txt
```

From `bash`,

```bsh
zsh -c 'autoload -U zargs; zargs -- ./*(.om) -- cat -- >Save.txt'
```

Comment: `zsh -c 'for name ( ./*(.om) ) cat $name' >Save.txt` means `./Save.txt` will be included in the expansion of `./*(.om)` and if there also are files with modification times in the future, you could end up in some infinite loop that fills up the disks.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Ah, because of the redirection happening before the invocation of `zsh -c`. Hopefully alleviated now by including the redirection in the `zsh` code instead.

Comment: Or use `autoload -U zargs; set -o extendedglob; { zargs -- ./^Save.txt(.om) -- cat -- ; } >Save.txt` to be on the safe side. Note that the GNU implementation of `cat` will refuse to read the file its stdout is opened on (if it's a regular file).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this, suppose we have these files:

```
$ cat a.txt 
a
$ cat b.txt 
b
$ cat c.txt 
c
$ ls -lt *.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 2 oct  7 09:21 a.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 2 oct  7 09:21 b.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 2 oct  7 09:21 c.txt
```

Then we run this command:

```bsh
$ ls -1t *.txt | xargs -I {} cat "{}" > Save.txt
$ cat Save.txt 
a
b
c
```

- `ls -1t` list just the names of the files.
- `xargs -I {} cat "{}"` performs a `cat` for each file passed as argument.

---

And an important note: [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead).

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of doing this, but one of the best if you want to stick to using just shell syntax and common utilities is to use the GNU versions of `find` (for the `-printf` option), `sort` and `sed` (for the `-z` option), and `xargs` (for `-0`):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%T@\t%p\0' |
  sort -z -r -n -k 1,1 |
  sed -z -e 's/^[^\t]*\t//' |
  xargs -0r cat > merged.txt
```

This will work with filenames containing **ANY** valid characters, including spaces, tabs, newlines and those used by the shell like `;`, `<`, `>`, `|`, and `&` - the only character which **isn't** valid in a filename is the NUL character, which is why it's being used as the filename separator (and why it's the only reliable filename separator to use).

The find command outputs all of the filenames in the current directory prefixed with their modification time (in seconds since the epoch) `%T@` and a tab `%t`, then the filename itself and a NUL character - this is effectively an enhanced `-print0` with a timestamp as well as the filename.  The `-maxdepth 1` option limits it to the current directory only - i.e. tells it not to recurse into sub-directories.

This is then piped into `sort` to reverse sort the filenames by the timestamps, and then into `sed` to remove the timestamp from before the filenames and then finally into `xargs` which `cat`s all the filenames it gets from STDIN.  Output is redirected to `merged.txt`.

---

BTW, if you're using FreeBSD or a Mac, FreeBSD's `find` also supports `-printf` and its version of `sort` supports `-z` and their `xargs` has `-0`.  Unfortunately, their version of sed doesn't support `-z`, so you'd have to use something else - `perl` would be a good substitute as its `-p` and `-n` options make it work very much like `sed`.   e.g. use the following in place of `sed` in the pipeline above:

```
perl -0 -p -e 's/^[^\t]*\t//'
```

or just install GNU `sed`.

BTW, there's no particular reason not to use perl on linux too - it's just that sed is smaller & simpler and has slightly less startup overhead than perl....a trivial difference on modern systems.

---

Alternatively, you could just do the whole thing in `perl`:

```
$ perl -e '@ARGV = sort { (stat($b))[9] <=> (stat($a))[9] } @ARGV;
    while (<>) {
      if ($ARGV eq "merged.txt") { close(ARGV); next } ; # skip to next file
      print
    }' -- * > merged.txt
```

In this, perl sorts its filename arguments by timestamp (using its built-in `stat` function, which returns an array with the modification timestamp as its 10th element, so we use `[9]` because perl arrays start from 0 rather than 1. See `perldoc -f stat`), then prints them out....excluding "merged.txt" which is the redirection target.  In essence, this is a re-implementation of `cat` in perl.

A fancier version would take a `-o outputfile` option or similar and open its own output file (and remove the output filename from @ARGV before sorting it - in case it already exists and is matched by the `*` glob), then it wouldn't need to hard-code an exclusion for the output file.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Getopt::Std;

getopts('o:', \%opts);
$opts{o} = '/dev/stdout' unless defined($opts{o}); # default to stdout
# alternatively, you could print an error message to STDERR and exit:
# die "-o option is required\n" unless defined($opts{o});

@ARGV = grep { ! /^$opts{o}$/ } @ARGV;
@ARGV = sort { (stat($b))[9] <=> (stat($a))[9] } @ARGV;

open($out,">",$opts{o});
while (<>) {
  print $out $_;
};
close($out);
```

You'd save this as somewhere in your $PATH (you don't want it in the current directory, otherwise it will be included in the output - there are ways to avoid this, but they'd make the script longer and a little more complicated than is wanted in a simple example), e.g., make it executable with `chmod`, and run this as:

```
merge.pl -o merged.txt -- *
```

Note: the `grep`, `stat`, and `sort` above are built-in perl functions, **not** the command line utilities.  You can get details about them with `perldoc -f`.

Comment: AFAIK, FreeBSD / macos `find` still doesn't support GNU's `-printf` (it supports `-print0` though). `sort` on BSDs **is** GNU `sort`, or at least used to be and still is on some. In any case, that explains why they support the GNU `sort` API.

Comment: So Apple not only have an ideological bias against GNU, they couldn't even be bothered to keep their BSD-based utils up to date.  great.